# How to get the state of the document whether it is locked or not in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, document-library, list-item

I have document library with workflow attached with it.

There are metadata columns attached with the document library i.e. Test1 & Test2

I am modifying the value of the Test1 & Test2 in the console application for changes required. I can successfully change the value of the metadata columns in the console if the document is not opened, but if the document is opened then it throws the error that the document is already locked.

I want to catch the state of the document whether it is locked or not before the error is generated. The reason behind of doing is that I have attached the workflow, if any error occurs the workflow will stop working.

My code for the console is:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://sp2013-15"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb)
                {
                    using (web)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SPList list = web.Lists["Documents"];
                            SPListItem item = list.Items[0];                            
                            item["TESt"] = "Managed";
                            item.Update();
                            Console.WriteLine("Changed");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                }



            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any property available for the `ListItem` to determine whether the item is locked or not?

What should I do to get idea of lock item?

Please help.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but it seems to be some issues with using statements in your code. You should not dispose SPSite.RootWeb object in SharePoint, and you dispose web object twice. It does not really matter in the simple console application, but could lead to some trouble if you reuse this code in some other applications. Just write the following line instead of the second and the third using statements: SPWeb = siteCollection.RootWeb

Comment: Try this solution, pretty sure it will work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: Thanks sir, @Tim I will keep in my mind from next time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found solution which runs perfectly in my case:

Use `LockedByUser` property of SPUser class.

The code `item.File.LockedByUser.LoginName` returns the user's log-in name who has locked the file. If it is not locked by anyone then it returns null.

The code is as below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@""))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb)
        {
            using (web)
            {
                try
                {

                    SPList list = web.Lists["Documents"];

                    SPListItem item = list.Items[0];

                    userName = item.File.LockedByUser.LoginName;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    {
                        item["TESt"] = "Changed k";
                        item.Update();
                        Console.WriteLine("Changed successfully");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry File is open");
                    }                    

                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                finally
                {
                    userName = string.Empty;   
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can check the Checked-Out status of the document.

```
if (item.Level == SPFileLevel.Checkout)
{
     // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Condition is not true, in case the file is opened. item.Level represents the `Published`..

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a built-in method to test if a file is locked in the sense that someone else has it open exclusively.  A technique I have used in the past is to rename the file using [`UpdateListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and then test the returned message.  If it works, I rename the file back to its original name; otherwise, SharePoint will tell me that the file is locked and who has it locked.